# why URI resources can change in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::prefix('keorganisasian')->as('keorganisasian.')->group(function () {
     Route::resource('karyawananggota', 'Admin\Keorganisasian\KaryawanAnggotaController');
)};
```

this error in php artisan route:list

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: im' so sorry  because a beginner at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not much to go on here but ... `Route::resource` will by default try to use the "singular" version of a resource name. `karyawananggota` passed through `Illuminate\Support\Str::singular()` yields `karyawananggotum`.

If you don't want this to be the case you can override this parameter for just this resource:

```
Route::resource(
    'karyawananggotum',
    '...',
    ['parameters' => ['karyawananggotum' => 'karyawananggotum']]
);
```

If you never want this to automatically happen for your resource names when used as parameters you can also adjust that globally:

```
Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar::singularParameters(false);
```

You can also map these resource names to parameters globally if needed as well.

Comment: thank you very much this works